# Как сделать чтобы видео было на всю высоту блока?

Tags: html, css, видео

Здравствуйте.

У меня в моем проекте CRM есть фоновое видео, которое на большом мониторе нормально отображается (во всю высоту блока), а вот если если изменить размер ширины окна браузера, то появляется пустое место...

**Как решить?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код HTML:

```
<div id="promo-index"> 

        <video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
            <source src="/images/ScreenCaptureProject3.mp4" type="video/webm"></source>
        </video>
        <div id="promo-bg">
            <div id="promo-wrap">
              <h1 class="main-title">CRM СИСТЕМА, КОТОРАЯ ПОЗВОЛИТ ВАМ  

                <ul id="ticker">
                    <li>ВЕСТИ СДЕЛКИ</li>
                    <li>УПРАВЛЯТЬ КЛИЕНТАМИ</li>
                    <li>КОНТРОЛИРОВАТЬ СОТРУДНИКОВ</li>
                    <li>СТАВИТЬ ЗАДАЧИ СОТРУДНИКАМ</li>
                    <li>СЛЕДИТЬ ЗА ИСПОЛНЕНИЕМ ЗАДАЧ</li>
                    <li>СОБИРАТЬ КЛИЕНТОВ С САЙТА</li>
                    <li>ЛОВИТЬ УХОДЯЩИХ КЛИЕНТОВ С САЙТА</li>
                    <li>ГРУППИРОВАТЬ КЛИЕНТОВ</li>
                    <li>ВЕСТИ И УПРАВЛЯТЬ НЕСКОЛЬКИМИ ПРОЕКТАМИ</li>
                    <li>АНАЛИЗИРОВАТЬ РАБОТУ</li>
                    <li>АНАЛИЗИРОВАТЬ ТРАФИК САЙТА</li>
                </ul>
              </h1>

            </div>
        </div>

 </div>
```

Код CSS:

```
  #promo-index{position: relative; width:100%; height:800px;}

    #promo-index > video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;/* 
        height: 100%; */
    }

  #promo-bg {background: url("../images/bg-dots.png"); height: 100%;  height: 100%;   width: 100%;   position: absolute;}
    #promo-wrap{width:950px; height:130px;margin:0 auto;padding-top:10%; text-align:center;}
        #promo-wrap span, #promo-wrap h1 {opacity:1 !important;}
        #promo-wrap span{display:block;}
            #promo-wrap .promo-tick {margin-top:40px;}
            #promo-wrap .promo-tick div:nth-child(1) {float: left; margin-left:0px;color:#fff; font-size:1.1em;}
            #promo-wrap .promo-tick div {float: left; margin-left:50px;color:#fff; font-size:1.3em;}
            #promo-wrap .promo-tick div .tick-item {margin-bottom:-5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


#promo-index{
   position: relative; 
   width:100%; 
   height:800px;
  
  overflow: hidden;/* Добавить */
}

/* Стили для видео */
#promo-index > video {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  width:2000px; 
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#promo-bg {
  background: url("../images/bg-dots.png"); 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#promo-wrap{
  max-width:950px; 
  width: 100%;
  height:130px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top:10%; 
  text-align:center;
}
#promo-wrap span, 
#promo-wrap h1 {
  opacity:1 !important;
}
#promo-wrap span{
  display:block;
}
#promo-wrap .promo-tick {
  margin-top:40px;
}
#promo-wrap .promo-tick div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left; 
  margin-left:0px;
  color:#fff; 
  font-size:1.1em;
}
#promo-wrap .promo-tick div {
  float: left; 
  margin-left:50px;
  color:#fff; 
  font-size:1.3em;
}
#promo-wrap .promo-tick div .tick-item {
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="promo-index"> 

<video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/distill-videos/videos/processed/2180/lighthouse.mp4" type="video/webm">
    </source>
</video>

 <div id="promo-bg">
    <div id="promo-wrap">
      <h1 class="main-title">CRM СИСТЕМА, КОТОРАЯ ПОЗВОЛИТ ВАМ  

        <ul id="ticker">
          <li>ВЕСТИ СДЕЛКИ</li>
          <li>УПРАВЛЯТЬ КЛИЕНТАМИ</li>
          <li>КОНТРОЛИРОВАТЬ СОТРУДНИКОВ</li>
          <li>СТАВИТЬ ЗАДАЧИ СОТРУДНИКАМ</li>
          <li>СЛЕДИТЬ ЗА ИСПОЛНЕНИЕМ ЗАДАЧ</li>
          <li>СОБИРАТЬ КЛИЕНТОВ С САЙТА</li>
          <li>ЛОВИТЬ УХОДЯЩИХ КЛИЕНТОВ С САЙТА</li>
          <li>ГРУППИРОВАТЬ КЛИЕНТОВ</li>
          <li>ВЕСТИ И УПРАВЛЯТЬ НЕСКОЛЬКИМИ ПРОЕКТАМИ</li>
          <li>АНАЛИЗИРОВАТЬ РАБОТУ</li>
          <li>АНАЛИЗИРОВАТЬ ТРАФИК САЙТА</li>
        </ul>
      </h1>

    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```